# Switch in Circuits

Tags: current, switches, time

I am really confused about what happens to the circuit when the switch is open or closed.

1. What does t=0 , t=0+ , t=0- , t<0 and t >0+ mean ?
2. what does it mean if the switch has been in position for a long time ?

Answer (score 6):

> What does t=0 , t=0+ , t=0- , t<0 and t >0+ mean ?

\$t=0\$ means at the time that we are referencing as 0.

\$t=0^+\$ means just after that time. For example, if a switch closes at time 0, then this would be just after the switch closes.

\$t=0^-\$ means just before time 0. For example, just before the switch closes.

\$t < 0\$ means the whole period of time before time 0.

\$t > 0\$ means the whole period of time after time 0.

> what does it mean if the switch has been in position for a long time ?

It means that all energy storage components (capacitors and inductors) have had enough time to become fully energized and their behavior in the circuit can be analyzed according to their dc behavior (capacitors act as opens, inductors act as shorts).